# Add class label to raw images for Augmented Pascal Voc dataset

Tags: python, image-processing, semantic-segmentation

I have recently downloaded an augmented Pascal Voc dataset from this dropbox link, which contains over 10000 images: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oeu149j8qtbs1x0/SegmentationClassAug.zip?dl=0

However, this contains just the raw class images:
[image: Raw class image]

I would like to get the class label images:
[image: Class images]

Is there any way to do this, or has someone already done this? I cannot find a way to make this conversion

Answer (score 0):

The class label for PASCAL_VOC  dataset

PASCAL_VOC_classes = {
0: 'background',
1: 'airplane',
2: 'bicycle',
3: 'bird',
4: 'boat',
5: 'bottle',
6: 'bus',
7: 'car',
8: 'cat',
9: 'chair',
10: 'cow',
11: 'table',
12: 'dog',
13: 'horse',
14: 'motorbike',
15: 'person',
16: 'potted_plant',
17: 'sheep',
18: 'sofa',
19 : 'train',
20 : 'tv',
21 : 'void'
}